# javascript flip image animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

my problem is my gif image can move randomly but i want to flip the image every 8sec.

i have keyframe for the image move from left to right

```
  @keyframes go-left-right {
    from { left: 0; }          
    to { left: calc(100%);  } 
}

.progress {
    animation: go-left-right 8s infinite alternate;
    width: 5%;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

then this is my javascript for randomly move.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  animateDiv('.progress');  });

 function makeNewPosition(){
  var h = $(window).height() - 25;
  var w = $(window).width() - 25;
  
  var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
  var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
  
  return [nh,nw];}

 function animateDiv(myclass){
  var newq = makeNewPosition();
  $(myclass).animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, 3000,   function(){
    animateDiv(myclass);  });  };
```

Comment: With "flip" do you mean to reposition the element to the left side of the window again or to flip the image inside the DIV?

Comment: i want the image flip every 8 seconds